# Last characters of a column of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table inside a data.frame, and I need to get only the last two characters from that table, how do I do this?

Note: I was trying to do it using str_sub, but in it I can only define which character starts and which ends, and my data varies the size of characters. Follow my example below that does not solve:

```
base$estado <- str_sub(psd_base$itbc_name, start = 2)
```

Comment: Please `dput(head(base,20))` and paste the output in the question in order to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `substr()` and `nchar()` to select the last letter of a character. Both are directly applicable to vectors, so you can write:

```
names = c("Alpha","Bip","Charlemagne","Haggs","O")
substr(names,nchar(names),nchar(names))
```

Which will give the output:

```
[1] "a" "p" "e" "s" "O"
```

Since I do not have a reproducible example of your data, this example has to suffice. I think you get the idea.